# OS X - Intercepting gestures

Tags: macos, cocoa

Can someone please tell me how applications such as BetterTouchTool intercept system wide mouse and trackpad gestures?

Comment: I suppose whatever they're using it won't be *MAS*-able ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that apps such as BTT are using the private MultiTouch API, with some help from the EventTap API.

Comment: do you know where or how I can find more information about this MultiTouch API?

Answer (score 0):

This answer should work for gestures as well:
**[How to emulate the cmd-shift-4 screen capture interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288772/how-to-emulate-the-cmd-shift-4-screen-capture-interface)**

except you'd want to override the *"Touch and Gesture Events"* methods of `NSResponder` instead in your custom view/window, like

- `magnifyWithEvent:`
- `rotateWithEvent:`
- `swipeWithEvent:`